# UICollectionView finishInteractiveTransition without animating completion

Tags: ios, ios7, uicollectionview, transition, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm implementing a custom interactive collection view layout transition, and would like to configure it so that on calling `finishInteractiveTransition` with a transition layout `transitionProgress` of 1.0, the completion block of `startInteractiveTransitionToCollectionViewLayout:completion:` is fired immediately.

I require this behaviour as I would like to be able to immediately start another transition after this one has finished. With this completion block not firing immediately, I end up with `nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar` in the log, since the transition context hasn't had its `completeTransition:` method called yet.

As it is, even when there is no animation required, there is a small delay of about 0.05s. Is it possible to force `UICollectionView` to not animate this completion?

---

#### Some code...

I have a transition controller that handles both animated & interactive transitions for a navigation transition. The relevant parts of that controller are as follows:

```
- (void)startInteractiveTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    self.context = transitionContext;
    UIView *inView = [self.context containerView];
    UICollectionViewController *fromCVC = (UICollectionViewController *)[self.context viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UICollectionViewController *toCVC = (UICollectionViewController *)[self.context viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    
    self.transitionLayout = (MyTransitionLayout *)[fromCVC.collectionView startInteractiveTransitionToCollectionViewLayout:toCVC.collectionViewLayout completion:^(BOOL completed, BOOL finish) {
        [self.context completeTransition:completed];
        [inView addSubview:toCVC.view];
    }];
}

- (void)updateInteractiveTransition:(CGFloat)progress
{
    if (!self.context) return;
    self.percentComplete = progress;
    if (self.percentComplete != self.transitionLayout.transitionProgress) {
        self.transitionLayout.transitionProgress = self.percentComplete;
        [self.transitionLayout invalidateLayout];
        [self.context updateInteractiveTransition:self.percentComplete];
    }
}

- (void)finishInteractiveTransition
{
    if (!self.context) return;
    UICollectionViewController *fromCVC = (UICollectionViewController *)[self.context viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    [fromCVC.collectionView finishInteractiveTransition];
    [self.context finishInteractiveTransition];
}

- (void)cancelInteractiveTransition
{
    if (!self.context) return;
    UICollectionViewController *fromCVC = (UICollectionViewController *)[self.context viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    [fromCVC.collectionView cancelInteractiveTransition];
    [self.context cancelInteractiveTransition];
}
```

I've verified that on calling `finishInteractiveTransition` the transition layout's `transitionProgress` is exactly 1.0. According to the `UIViewControllerTransitioning.h` header file, the `completionSpeed` defaults to 1.0, resulting in a completion duration of `(1 - percentComplete)*duration`, so the duration should be 0, but it's not... it's taking at least a couple of run loops before the completion block is called.

Is it possible to do what I want, or will I have to implement my own version of `startInteractiveTransitionToCollectionViewLayout:completion:`? (not the end of the world, but I'd rather stick to the standard APIs where possible...)

Comment: Hi @Stuart, have you sort out anything? When I run startInteractiveTransitionToCollectionViewLayout:completion: I want it to return my custom LayoutTransition class

Comment: @Carvalho Hi, I've been sidetracked from this issue, but will return to it soon. Your problem is unrelated to this though; just implement the `collectionView:transitionLayoutForOldLayout:newLayout:` method on your collection view's delegate and return an instance of your custom transition layout. Then, when you start an interactive transition on the collection view, it will call that delegate method to acquire the transition layout.